Yaml number type not being recognised as a integer
Got a little problem which I am sure a Yaml guru will quickly solve for me.
We have a set of parameters thus on a Azure pipeline Yaml file
parameters:
  - name: customers
    type: object
    default:
      - name: module
        type: string
        default: Warmup
      - name: timeout
        type: number
        default: 20

      - name: module
        type: string
        default: Sidebar
      - name: timeout
        type: number
        default: 15

and so on, further down the yaml file we have a loop
- ${{ each section in parameters.customers }}:
  - task: VSTest@3
    displayName: 'Testing - ${{ section.module }} '
    inputs:
      testAssemblyVer2: 'C:\Code\Release\net7.0\CodeRegression.dll'
      searchFolder: 'C:\Code\Release\net7.0\'
      testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=${{ section.name }}'
      testRunTitle: 'Regression ${{ section.name }}'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    continueOnError: true
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    timeoutInMinutes: ${{ section.timeout }}

But I get an error

And validate shows this

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong please?

You can also check more details about the usage of Parameter data type object here.

Please note there's no such thing as schemas for the Azure pipelines parameters. You can define a parameter as object, but there's no way to enforce a specific structure and types for each property.
Instead of:
parameters:
  - name: customers
    type: object
    default:
      - name: module        
        type: string
        default: Warmup
      - name: timeout       
        type: number
        default: 20

      - name: module        
        type: string
        default: Sidebar
      - name: timeout       
        type: number
        default: 15

You can define an array with 2 elements like this:
parameters:
  - name: customers
    type: object
    default:
      - module: Warmup
        timeout: 20

      - module: Sidebar
        timeout: 15

I'm not completely sure if only 2 properties (module and timeout) are required in your specific scenario for each element, but obviously more can be added if required.
Using parameters.customers:
- ${{ each section in parameters.customers }}:
  - task: VSTest@3
    displayName: 'Testing - ${{ section.module }} '
    inputs:
      testAssemblyVer2: 'C:\Code\Release\net7.0\CodeRegression.dll'
      searchFolder: 'C:\Code\Release\net7.0\'
      testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=${{ section.module }}'
      testRunTitle: 'Regression ${{ section.module }}'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    continueOnError: true
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    timeoutInMinutes: ${{ section.timeout }}


@Kev please let me know if my answer is not clear enough.

Hi, that comment was on the wrong message, I will look at your suggestions tonight and let you know. Thanks

Hi, I tried that as you suggested and still the same error

@Kev exactly the same errors? Have you changed the VSTest@3 accordingly? Please note that ${{ section.name }}  won't work with my solution because property name is not defined. You can of course add it to the customers parameter if it's really needed.

@Kev I've just created a dummy pipeline. I can confirm my proposed changes (parameter and task) compile without any errors. Please double-check your code, specially the ${{ section.xxxx }} parts.

Thanks for the feedback, I will be back at my office on Wednesday and I will have another look then. - Kev

Just had a look at this. So  rebuilt the pipeline from scratch and although it did show the error I was able to validate and save and then run the pipline with no problems at all. I then reopened the yaml in edit mode and I no longer see the error message so all sort now, many thanks Rui

What's more, Be caution here, If you use timeoutInMinutes in task level, it should be the type of string not number. reference
steps:
- task: string # Required as first property. Name of the task to run.
  inputs: # Inputs for the task. string: string # Name/value pairs
  condition: string # Evaluate this condition expression to determine whether to run this task.
  continueOnError: boolean # Continue running even on failure?
  displayName: string # Human-readable name for the task.
  target: string | target # Environment in which to run this task.
  enabled: boolean # Run this task when the job runs?
  env: # Variables to map into the process's environment. string: string # Name/value pairs
  name: string # ID of the step.
  timeoutInMinutes: string # Time to wait for this task to complete before the server kills it.
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: string # Number of retries if the task fails.

If in job timeoutInMinutes need the type number. reference

